# Elemento no toma el estilo que le corresponde

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo css y no entiendo por qué el elemento que div **#prueba-medidas** que estoy especificando no toma el color de fondo correspondiente.

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
}

#titulo-principal {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: blueviolet;
}

img {
  width: 250px;
}

.comidas-preferidas {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.comida {
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  margin: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: chocolate;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: green;
}

div {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.lista-gatos {
  font-size: 25px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 10px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin: 5px;
}

a[href="https://freecodecamp.org/espanol/"] {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#prueba-medidas {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <main>
    <h1 id="titulo-principal">Aplicación de Gatitos</h1>
    <p>Haz click aquí para ver mas <a href="https://freecodecamp.org/espanol/" target="_blank">imágenes de gatitos.</a></p>

    <a href="#"><img src="https://bit.ly/fcc-relaxing-cat" alt="Un lindo gato naranja recostado sobre su espalda."></a>

    <hr>

    <h3>Listas de Gatos</h3>

    <div>
      <p>Cosas que los gatos <em>aman</em>:</p>
      <ul class="lista-gatos">
        <li>Menta gatuna</li>
        <li>Apuntadores Láser</li>
        <li><s>Lasaña</s></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="comidas-preferidas">
        <img src="imagenes/lasana.jpg" alt="Lasaña" class="comida">
      </div>

      <p>Cosas que los gatos <strong>odian</strong>:</p>
      <ol class="lista-gatos">
        <li>Tratamientos antipulgas</li>
        <li>Truenos</li>
        <li>Otros gatos</li>
      </ol>
      <img src="imagenes/gatos.jpg" alt="Grupo de gatitos pequeños.">
    </div>

    <form action="/enviar-respuesta">
      <!-- Botones de Radio -->
      <label for="interior">
        <input type="radio" id="interior" value="interior" name="interior-exterior" checked>Interior
      </label>
      <br>
      <label for="exterior">
        <input type="radio" id="exterior" value="exterior" name="interior-exterior">Exterior
      </label>
      <br>

      <!-- Botones de verificación -->
      <label for="carinoso">
        <input type="checkbox" id="carinoso" value="carinoso" name="personalidad" checked>Cariñoso
      </label><br>
      <label for="perezoso">
        <input type="checkbox" id="perezoso" value="perezoso" name="personalidad">Perezoso
      </label><br>
      <label for="energico">
        <input type="checkbox" id="energico" value="energico" name="personalidad">Enérgico
      </label><br>

      <!-- Entrada de texto -->
      <input type="text" placeholder="URL de la foto de tu gato" required><br>

      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    <div id="prueba-medidas">
      <div class="rectangulo px">200px de Ancho</div>
      <div class="rectangulo vw">20vw de Ancho</div>
      <div class="rectangulo em">15em de Ancho</div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p><small>Sin derechos de Autor - <a href="https://freecodecamp.org/espanol/">freeCodeCamp</a></small></p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Mi inquietud es por qué todos los divs toman el color aquamarine si posteriormente siendo mas especifico con el ID le asigno el color amarillo.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que TODA la superficie del `div` #prueba-medidas está ocupado por sus hijos, que son `div`normales y por tanto tienen el fondo `aquamarine`. Si añadimos un espacio entre elementos al div padre, vemos el color del fondo

```css
div {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin: 10px;
}

#prueba-medidas {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="prueba-medidas">
  Texto en el padre
  <div class="rectangulo px">200px de Ancho</div>
  <div class="rectangulo vw">20vw de Ancho</div>
  <div class="rectangulo em">15em de Ancho</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, respuesta muy clara, muchas gracias.